# PrimeZetaP evaluation in different versions of Mathematica

Tags: evaluation, special-functions, number-theory

[`PrimeZetaP`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimeZetaP.html) was introduced in version 7.0. I suspect there were made some changes in the definition of this function in subsequent versions.

Is there any user that has access to some/all of older versions 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 of Mathematica?

I would like to evaluate the following in all these versions (my version is 13.0.1):

```
s1 = 0.253751610037541116925066801039228316076296569416665 + 
   I 4.758114796091406094159521238042649851215029637674056;
s2 = 1.061924175922070760849961795694611252138683809658062 + 
   I 23.71733039185105166927978021531858411774100434863245;
PrimeZetaP[s1]
PrimeZetaP[s2]
```

---

```
0.*10^-49 + 6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394338798750 I

0.*10^-49 + 0.*10^-49 I
```

Why I suspect there were some changes in the definition of the function explains this code from [oeis](https://oeis.org/A358969):

```
FindRoot[PrimeZetaP[z] == If[$VersionNumber < 12.3, 0, 2*Pi*I], {z, 1 + 23.7*I}
```

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 evaluates : {0.*10^-49 + 6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394338798750 I, 
 0.*10^-49 + 0.*10^-49 I}

Comment: Note that the definition mentioned in the details seems to be unchanged from [version 7](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/PrimeZetaP.html). However, the documentation was expanded when going from [v11.3](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v11.3/ref/PrimeZetaP.html) to [v12](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v12/ref/PrimeZetaP.html). So if any implementation changes were made (and not mentioned), it is likely they happened at that time ... Also, do you have any good reasons to believe something was changed? :D

Comment: @Domen: Look at Mathematica section for code that is dependent on version, I think the author has some reason to put there the dependence on the version: https://oeis.org/A358969

Comment: Interesting! I certainly suggest you put this information right up in the question :)